# Meaning of Identity function in following method

Tags: haskell, boolean, identity

If the count of True's in the list is odd then the function returns True otherwise False.

For example:

```
xor [False, True, False] == True
xor [False, True, False, False, True] == False
```

Can someone explain me what "filter (id)" is accomplishing here:

```
xor :: [Bool] -> Bool
xor = foldr (\b a -> not b || not a) False . filter (id)
```

Comment: I might be confused, but wouldn't `xor = odd . length . filter (id)` do the same thing in a more readable manner?

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr Yes it would, but the exercise said to use a fold.

Comment: For those checking their answers to cis194 hw4: I guarantee there is a much nicer solution. You can do better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `filter (id)` will filter out all `False`s from a list.  `filter` has the type

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

Since `xor` says explicitly it takes an argument of type `[Bool]`, we can say that `a` is `Bool` in this case.  Substituting back in to `filter`'s type to make it less general we get

```
filter :: (Bool -> Bool) -> [Bool] -> [Bool]
```

And similarly for `id`'s type:

```
id :: Bool -> Bool
```

So whenever `id` returns `True`, `filter` keeps that element, and whenever it returns `False` that element is discarded.  So

```
> filter id [True]
[True]
> filter id [False]
[]
> filter id [True, False, True]
[True, True]
> filter id [False, True, False]
[True]
```

The output can only ever be a list of `True`s.

---

Another way to look at it is to create your own predicate function for use with `filter`:

```
isTrue :: Bool -> Bool
isTrue True = True
isTrue False = False
```

Then you could write

```
xor = foldr (\b a -> not b || not a) False . filter isTrue
```

But it's pretty easy to see that `isTrue` is the same as `id` for `Bool` values since there's only 2 cases to handle:

```
isTrue True  == True  == id True
isTrue False == False == id False
```

Comment: "So whenever id returns True, filter keeps that element, and whenever it returns False that element is discarded."
Why does it keep True and not False?

Comment: @Michiel Think about how filter works.  If I did `filter (<5) [1..10] == [1,2,3,4]`, it would calculate `(<5)` for every element in `[1..10]`.  When `(<5)` returns `True`, that element is returned, if `(<5)` returns `False`, that element is discarded.  So it would see `1 < 5 == True` so `1` is in the output list, but `5 < 5 == False` so `5` won't appear in the output list.